# Using Greek letters in LaTeX tables

Tags: r, unicode, knitr

I have the following Rnw document which I intend should produce a small table with "a b c" and "α β γ". At the moment, the encoding seems to be causing problems. The funny thing is that the output in the pdf is different to that in the R console. The following example doesn't throw any errors, but doesn't have the Greek letters I want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<makegreek>>=
greek <- c("\U03B1", "\U03B2", "\U03B3")
greek
@

<<r grecoroman>>=
gr <- data.frame(roman=letters[1:3], greek=greek)
gr
@

<<gr-table, results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(gr))
@

\end{document}
```

[image: All Greek to me]

I also tried adding the line: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to my preamble, but that simply throws an error: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:? not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Comment: Worth a read http://www.eelvex.net/latex/greek-in-latex/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is my first thought, but I feel fairly certain that a better way exists:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
<<makegreek>>=
greek <- c("$\\alpha$", "$\\beta$", "$\\gamma$")
greek
@

<<r grecoroman>>=
gr <- data.frame(roman=letters[1:3], greek=greek)
gr
@

<<gr-table, results='asis'>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(gr),sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
@

\end{document}
```

Following @mnel's suggestion above, this also seems to work (leaving the rest of my soltuion unchanged):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
<<makegreek>>=
greek <- c("\\greektext a", "\\greektext b", "\\greektext c")
greek
@
```

As this was migrated from StackOverflow, I thought I would explain a few things that might be confusing to people familiar with LaTeX but not with R.

The R code here is generating LaTeX and inserting it into the document. Backslashes are special characters in R, so we need to escape them (e.g. `\\alpha`). Next, we have to tell the `xtable` function to *not* try to process the table entries, since it will typically assume that you want it to convert certain special characters to literals (like `\backslash`). So I'm simply passing an identity function that does nothing in

```
sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
```

Comment: Son of a pup beat me by 23 seconds +1